# What is the meaning of O(V+E) space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Time complexity, `O(v+e)` is quite clear that it is similar to 2 loops(e times and v times) running separately in a program.

But, I am confused when the same comes to space complexity.

Is it like, first allocate `O(v)` space then free it and then allocate `O(e)` space?

Thanks!

Comment: It's equivalent to using `O(v)+O(e)` space. Essentially (I'm assuming you're dealing with graphs, here), it means you're using some storage space for each vertex and some space for each edge (maybe you have a `List<Vertex>` and a `List<Edge>`, or something).

Comment: ok, got it.!
yes, its in context to adjacency list representation of graph.
Thanks.

Comment: @Michelle
What if above is the case?
As in, we allocate O(v) space then free it , then again allocate O(e) space; what will be the space complexity?

Comment: That would be `O(max(v,e))`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it enough.!:)

Comment: @phoenix: just in case you didn't see the comments to the answers below, O(max(v,e)) = O(v+e) = O(v) + O(e), so you can use any of those three; in my experience with algorithm analysis, the usually preferred one of those three choices is O(v+e).

Comment: @G.Bach
Thanks for clearing it further..It was helpful.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're dealing with time complexity, addition (`O(v+e)`) means two things are happening sequentially. When you move to space complexity, the `+` sign should be used in context of space, not time.

`O(v+e)` space equivalent to using `O(v)+O(e)` space. Essentially (I'm assuming you're dealing with graphs, here), it means you're using some storage space for each vertex and some space for each edge (maybe you have a `List<Vertex>` and a `List<Edge>`, or something) - most likely all at the same time.

In your example of allocating `O(v)` memory, freeing it, and then allocating `O(e)` memory, you're using `O(max(v,e))` space at any time.

Edit: As G. Bach pointed out, `O(v+e)` will always be equivalent to `O(max(v,e))`. I would argue that there are cases where one or the other would be more appropriate in terms of clarity (one or the other will better express what space/time is actually being used), but that's subjective. If this is for a class, your instructor may prefer one notation over the other - it should be obvious from class notes, or you can ask. But in short, `O(v+e)` is appropriate for both situations that have been described.

Comment: "When you're dealing with time complexity, addition (O(v+e)) means two things are happening sequentially." I don't know what this is supposed to mean, but I assume you mean that the algorithm consists of two parts, one of which takes O(v) and the other O(e) time. This is incorrect. The plus sign does not necessarily stem from an algorithm with sequential stages of differing complexity; it is also possible that the plus sign is a way to express "the maximum of these two dominates complexity" without the algorithm having different phases. For example, this is why BFS has O(|V| + |E|) complexity.

Comment: Another algorithm to visualize this more clearly is finding the connected components of a graph using BFS or DFS. This has O(|V| + |E|) time complexity as well, and for graphs with fewer edges than nodes we get |V| > |E| and so O(|V| + |E|) = O(|V|), but for graphs with more edges than nodes this gives us O(|V| + |E|) = O(|E|).

Comment: When you point out the equivalency, it's super-obvious. I blame Monday morning and no coffee. I would argue that using one version over the other adds clarity depending on the situation, but both are correct.

Comment: Using max instead of + could clarify, but since Big-Oh isn't supposed to be accurate and the terms don't mean different things formally, trying for semantic accuracy with Big-Oh is a lost cause. If the precise usage of time and/or space is relevant, then Big-Oh is simply the wrong tool to do it.